# Code is compilied but cant creat symble block to use in the block diagram

Tags: vhdl, quartus

I am using Quartus 2 13.0 sp1(32 bit). The code compiles correctly but when I want to create symble I get an error.

I tried to check the error on google but did not find it. As I understand the problem is with integer `f_in`. for some reason when I put `f_in` in `clk_out_full_num` I get this error. Why do I get this error if the code compiles correctly?

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;
use IEEE.Numeric_Std.ALL;


---------->>>>>>> this block is used to divide clock by 2 for every bit<<<<<<<<<<-------------
---------->>>>>>> this block also is used to manuely choose the ferquincy of the signal <<<<-------

entity Clock_Divider is 
        GENERIC(        resulation      :   INTEGER := 4    );  --size of the binary input numbers in bits

        port ( 
                Frequency_num : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(resulation-1 downto 0);-- this is used to change the ferquincy using manuel buttens 
                f_in: in integer;
                clk_in : in std_logic ;
                clr  : in std_logic;
                clk_out: out std_logic;
                clk_out_full_num: out std_logic_vector (f_in downto 0)

                );
        end Clock_Divider;          

architecture logic_clock_divider  of Clock_Divider is 
    signal q:std_logic_vector (16 downto 0);    

signal bit_number : integer;-- this signal is used to convert Frequency_num(STD_LOGIC_VECTOR)--- to >>> integer

    begin 
    bit_number <= to_integer(unsigned(Frequency_num));  --the converstion it self Frequency_num(STD_LOGIC_VECTOR)--- to >>> integer

        --clock_divider 
        process(clk_in,clr )
        begin 

            if (clk_in'event and clk_in='1') then 
                q<= q+1;
            end if;
        end process;

        clk_out <=q(bit_number);

        clk_out_full_num<=q;

    end logic_clock_divider ;
```

> Internal Error: Sub-system: VRFX, File:
>   /quartus/synth/vrfx/vrfx_analyzer_impl.cpp, Line: 2967 port_constraint
>   Stack Trace:
>       0x52a03: VRFX_ANALYZER_IMPL::vhdl_set_port_and_parameter_to_hdb_entity + 0xb33 
>       0x48a71: VRFX_ANALYZER_IMPL::analyze + 0x2f1 
>       0x483dc: VRFX_ANALYZER::analyze + 0xc 
>       0x6a3f8: SGN_ANALYZER::analyze + 0x148 
>       0x721a0: SGN_ANALYZER::process_curr_vrfx_file + 0x410 
>       0x72965: SGN_ANALYZER::process_curr_file + 0x355 
>       0x11a49: sgn_source_file_processing + 0x89 
>        0x47d5: qsyn_execute_sgn + 0x2a5 
>       0x1c924: QSYN_FRAMEWORK::execute_core + 0x104 
>       0x1f12f: QSYN_FRAMEWORK::execute + 0x15f 
>       0x11562: qexe_get_tcl_sub_option + 0x1f32 
>       0x13a38: qexe_process_cmdline_arguments + 0x488 
>       0x13bd4: qexe_standard_main + 0x84 
>       0x19dd6: qsyn_main + 0xa6 
>        0x4e21: msg_main_thread + 0x11 
>        0x1c98: _thr_final_wrapper + 0x8 
>        0x5515: msg_thread_wrapper + 0x85 
>        0x3921: mem_thread_wrapper + 0x31 
>        0x60f1: msg_exe_main + 0x81 
>       0x1ba1c: _main + 0x1c 
>       0x24cd7: __ftol2 + 0x1e1 
>       0x162c3: BaseThreadInitThunk + 0x23 
>       0x61f68: RtlSubscribeWnfStateChangeNotification + 0x438 
>       0x61f33: RtlSubscribeWnfStateChangeNotification + 0x403
>
> End-trace
>
> Quartus II 32-bit Version 13.0.1 Build 232 06/12/2013 SJ Web Edition
>   Service Pack Installed:
>    1

Comment: I don't know why your code is compiling, but you can't use a input of an entity to define another input width.

Answer (score 0):

I don´t know how you synthesize your code. When I copy the code into my Vivavo the IDE shows two errors:

```
15 - f_in cannot be used within its own interface list

19 - f_in is illegal in an expression
```

If you want a variable width for your input use a `generic` like you do it before.

```
Generic (   InputSize       : INTEGER := 4;
            OutputSize      : INTEGER := 5
            );
Port (      Frequency_num : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(InputSize - 1 downto 0);
            clk_in : in STD_LOGIC;
            clr  : in STD_LOGIC;
            clk_out: out STD_LOGIC;
            clk_out_full_num: out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(OutputSize - 1 downto 0)
            );
```

You have to set a fix value for the hardware synthesis. You can´t create a hardware with a variable bus width!

Set the width of `q` to the width of `clk_out_full_num`

```
signal q:std_logic_vector (OutputSize - 1 downto 0);
```

and you can synthesize your code.